# Preventing crashing when listening for a connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets

Is there any way of preventing my application from temporarily crashing as soon as I create a socket? This program unfreezes as soon as it receives a connection but it can be misleading to users.

I have tried putting the socket creation methods etc. in a thread and running it from there but that did not work.

Edit: Unless it would be feasible to give the socket a set amount of time and then disconnect once it expires?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us the multi-threaded code you tried but didn't work?

Comment: Here are the steps I look + the code: http://pastebin.com/aDJ8xXcT

Comment: @Andrei0427 Can you show **real** code? The code in your link could either work or not work depending on how you use it.

Comment: @assylias , here is all my code, I wasnt entirely sure what to remove to not clutter, so Im just going to paste it all http://pastebin.com/C88HKDZU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it in a separate thread is the right way, since the Socket.accept() call is blocking (i.e. it blocks the thread you call it on, until it gets a connection).

There must be something wrong with your thread architecture. Post some code and maybe I can tell You what exactly.

EDIT: Giving the socket a short timeout will either not avoid the blocking, or timeout before someone connects, while getting a connection before the timeout will not have any difference from the current setup.

Comment: I have commented on my question with code and thread achitecture I used.

Comment: As far as I can tell all that code runs in a single thread. There are no Thread objects anywhere.

Comment: I can't comment on another answer or the question itself for some reason, so I'll just leave it here:

All that code runs in a single thread. I don't know about java.nio, but what I'd do is move that run() to a separate Runnable class, then call something like:

`Thread thread = new thread (new RunnableClass());                
                thread.start();`
Note that socket.read() also blocks, so that must be done by the other thread as well. And if You will have multiple connections, You  will need one thread for accepting them and then a thread for each to do the reading.

Answer (score 0):

You program does not crash, it is simply waiting for a connection because the `java.io` library is blocking.

To prevent waiting for a connection, you can either use the non-blocking `java.nio` classes *or* start a new `Thread` and let this new thread be the one that is waiting for the connection.

Comment: Are the socket creation classes being 'blocked'?

Comment: how would I go about 'converting' the thread to nonBlocking using the java.nio library?

Comment: If you only need one socket then I would go for the threaded approach. Otherwise, you should have a look at the NIO examples from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/index.html. The NBTimeServer example in particular might be interesting to you.